# Intel wireless 3160 not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, intel, iwlwifi

The wireless was working fine under 18.04 and earlier LTS's, but at some stage became intermittent (dropping out at 4am for example) and needing a reboot. Upgraded to 20.04 and it worked for a short time but then failed and has never worked since.By 'not working' I mean the device driver is not loaded correctly so the wireless card is not seen by Linux which means nothing can be done through it. Ethernet is fine. I've googled and seen many solutions which don't work for me (re-installing network manager for example). Any help appreciated. It's a relatively old Gigabyte NUC GB-BXi7-5500
[update on booting under 16.04 added at end]

lspci reports

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

uname -a reports

```
Linux Desktop 5.15.0-53-generic #59-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 17 18:53:30 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 reports

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8070]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
```

lshw -C network reports

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7100000-f7101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 0c
       serial: fc:aa:14:a9:65:39
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-53-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.1.109 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7000000-f7000fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

After clearing dmesg and rebooting,
dmesg | grep iwl reports

```
[   15.804047] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 3160-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   17.624157] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   17.641903] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: d0:7e:35:6b:fd:9b
[   19.649567] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT calibrations: -110
[   19.649616] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   19.667045] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 628 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2054 __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access.part.0+0x200/0x240 [iwlwifi]
[   19.667071] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi ledtrig_audio mei_hdcp snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hda_intel iwlmvm(+) intel_rapl_msr snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi mac80211 snd_hda_codec i915 btusb pwc snd_hda_core intel_rapl_common libarc4 btrtl ttm drm_kms_helper snd_hwdep videobuf2_vmalloc btbcm videobuf2_memops snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_rawmidi intel_powerclamp snd_seq videobuf2_v4l2 cec videobuf2_common snd_seq_device videodev coretemp rc_core mc btintel snd_timer kvm_intel kvm iwlwifi input_leds i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect snd bluetooth cfg80211 sysimgblt crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel mei_me mei aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd rapl ecdh_generic ecc soundcore intel_cstate at24 mac_hid acpi_pad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport pstore_blk ramoops pstore_zone drm reed_solomon efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid r8169 i2c_i801
[   19.667155] RIP: 0010:__iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access.part.0+0x200/0x240 [iwlwifi]
[   19.667200]  iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x45/0x80 [iwlwifi]
[   19.667221]  iwl_force_nmi+0x80/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[   19.667237]  iwl_trans_sync_nmi_with_addr+0x55/0x130 [iwlwifi]
[   19.667254]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0x40/0x50 [iwlwifi]
[   19.667274]  iwl_fw_dbg_error_collect+0x67/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   19.667297]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x8ed/0xbb0 [iwlmvm]
[   19.667330]  _iwl_op_mode_start+0x78/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   19.667348]  iwl_opmode_register+0x6d/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   19.667367]  iwl_mvm_init+0x3a/0x1000 [iwlmvm]
[   19.667481] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[   19.667526] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[   19.667751] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 08b38086 00100000 02800083 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.667808] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 80708086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 00000100
[   19.667865] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000040: 00020010 10008ec0 001b0c10 0006ec11 10110000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.667922] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000005 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.667982] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000080: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.668038] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.668095] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000000 00804005 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.668151] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.668208] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000100: 14010001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00002000 00002000 00000014 40000001
[   19.668264] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000120: 0000000f f710000c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.668321] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000140: 14c10003 ff6bfd9b d07e35ff 15410018 00000000 0001000b 0141cafe 00f01e1f
[   19.668381] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[   19.668444] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[   19.668501] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[   19.668559] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[   19.668620] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00002000 00002000 00000014 40000001
[   19.668676] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 0000000f f710000c 00000000
[   19.668713] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.2) config registers:
[   19.668840] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000000: 9c948086 00100407 060400e3 00810010 00000000 00000000 00020200 200000f0
[   19.668897] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000020: f710f710 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 00120303
[   19.668954] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000040: 01428010 00008000 00110000 03323c12 70110040 0014b200 01480000 00000008
[   19.669010] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000060: 00000000 00000817 00000000 00000000 00010002 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.669067] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000080: 00019005 fee00258 00000000 00000000 0000a00d 10001458 00000000 00000000
[   19.669123] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 000000a0: c8030001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.669180] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000 00001842 0b118008 00000000
[   19.669237] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 000000e0: 00400302 00000000 0000000b 00000000 00000050 0c000040 08030fb1 00000004
[   19.669293] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000100: 20000000 00000000 00000000 00060011 00000081 00002000 00000000 00000000
[   19.669350] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.669406] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000140: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.669462] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000160: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.669529] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000180: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.669577] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 000001a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.669623] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 000001c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.669670] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 000001e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   19.669716] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000200: 0001001e 0028281f 40a0281f
[   19.687180] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 628 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwl-trans.h:1341 iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x532/0x5b0 [iwlwifi]
[   19.687206] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi ledtrig_audio mei_hdcp snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hda_intel iwlmvm(+) intel_rapl_msr snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi mac80211 snd_hda_codec i915 btusb pwc snd_hda_core intel_rapl_common libarc4 btrtl ttm drm_kms_helper snd_hwdep videobuf2_vmalloc btbcm videobuf2_memops snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_rawmidi intel_powerclamp snd_seq videobuf2_v4l2 cec videobuf2_common snd_seq_device videodev coretemp rc_core mc btintel snd_timer kvm_intel kvm iwlwifi input_leds i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect snd bluetooth cfg80211 sysimgblt crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel mei_me mei aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd rapl ecdh_generic ecc soundcore intel_cstate at24 mac_hid acpi_pad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport pstore_blk ramoops pstore_zone drm reed_solomon efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid r8169 i2c_i801
[   19.687276] RIP: 0010:iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x532/0x5b0 [iwlwifi]
[   19.687319]  iwl_fwrt_dump_error_logs+0x29/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   19.687339]  iwl_mvm_nic_error+0x61/0xf0 [iwlmvm]
[   19.687363]  iwl_trans_sync_nmi_with_addr+0xa3/0x130 [iwlwifi]
[   19.687378]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0x40/0x50 [iwlwifi]
[   19.687395]  iwl_fw_dbg_error_collect+0x67/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   19.687414]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x8ed/0xbb0 [iwlmvm]
[   19.687438]  _iwl_op_mode_start+0x78/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   19.687453]  iwl_opmode_register+0x6d/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   19.687469]  iwl_mvm_init+0x3a/0x1000 [iwlmvm]
[   19.687570] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
[   19.710986] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 17.3216344376.0 3160-17.ucode
[   19.711040] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   19.711080] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   19.711113] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   19.711145] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   19.711176] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   19.711208] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   19.711240] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   19.711268] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[   19.711296] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   19.711325] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   19.711356] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   19.711385] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   19.711414] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   19.711443] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   19.711473] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   19.711507] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   19.711541] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   19.711575] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   19.711605] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[   19.711637] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   19.711664] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   19.711692] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   19.711719] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   19.711747] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   19.711775] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   19.711802] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   19.711833] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   19.711863] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   19.711894] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   19.711925] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   19.711957] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   19.711989] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   19.712019] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   19.712049] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   21.621546] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   21.789221] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: retry init count 0
[   21.789291] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   22.752518] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[   22.752527] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[   22.752530] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   22.787340] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 628 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwl-trans.h:1341 iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x532/0x5b0 [iwlwifi]
[   22.787363] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi ledtrig_audio mei_hdcp snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hda_intel iwlmvm(+) intel_rapl_msr snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi mac80211 snd_hda_codec i915 btusb pwc snd_hda_core intel_rapl_common libarc4 btrtl ttm drm_kms_helper snd_hwdep videobuf2_vmalloc btbcm videobuf2_memops snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_rawmidi intel_powerclamp snd_seq videobuf2_v4l2 cec videobuf2_common snd_seq_device videodev coretemp rc_core mc btintel snd_timer kvm_intel kvm iwlwifi input_leds i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect snd bluetooth cfg80211 sysimgblt crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel mei_me mei aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd rapl ecdh_generic ecc soundcore intel_cstate at24 mac_hid acpi_pad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport pstore_blk ramoops pstore_zone drm reed_solomon efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid r8169 i2c_i801
[   22.787420] RIP: 0010:iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x532/0x5b0 [iwlwifi]
[   22.787450]  iwl_fwrt_dump_error_logs+0x29/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   22.787464]  iwl_mvm_nic_error+0x61/0xf0 [iwlmvm]
[   22.787481]  iwl_trans_sync_nmi_with_addr+0xa3/0x130 [iwlwifi]
[   22.787491]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0x40/0x50 [iwlwifi]
[   22.787503]  iwl_fw_dbg_error_collect+0x67/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   22.787516]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x8ed/0xbb0 [iwlmvm]
[   22.787532]  _iwl_op_mode_start+0x78/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   22.787542]  iwl_opmode_register+0x6d/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   22.787553]  iwl_mvm_init+0x3a/0x1000 [iwlmvm]
[   22.787626] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
[   22.810971] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 17.3216344376.0 3160-17.ucode
[   22.810977] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   22.810979] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   22.810980] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   22.810982] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   22.810983] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   22.810984] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   22.810985] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   22.810986] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[   22.810987] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   22.810989] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   22.810990] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   22.810991] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   22.810992] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   22.810993] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   22.810995] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   22.810996] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   22.810997] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   22.810998] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   22.810999] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[   22.811001] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   22.811002] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   22.811003] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   22.811004] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   22.811005] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   22.811006] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   22.811007] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   22.811009] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   22.811010] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   22.811011] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   22.811012] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   22.811013] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   22.811014] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   22.811016] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   22.811017] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   24.720919] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[   24.888591] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: retry init count 1
[   24.888662] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   25.852267] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[   25.852276] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[   25.852279] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   25.887097] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 628 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwl-trans.h:1341 iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x532/0x5b0 [iwlwifi]
[   25.887127] Modules linked in: binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi ledtrig_audio mei_hdcp snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hda_intel iwlmvm(+) intel_rapl_msr snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi mac80211 snd_hda_codec i915 btusb pwc snd_hda_core intel_rapl_common libarc4 btrtl ttm drm_kms_helper snd_hwdep videobuf2_vmalloc btbcm videobuf2_memops snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_rawmidi intel_powerclamp snd_seq videobuf2_v4l2 cec videobuf2_common snd_seq_device videodev coretemp rc_core mc btintel snd_timer kvm_intel kvm iwlwifi input_leds i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect snd bluetooth cfg80211 sysimgblt crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel mei_me mei aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd rapl ecdh_generic ecc soundcore intel_cstate at24 mac_hid acpi_pad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport pstore_blk ramoops pstore_zone drm reed_solomon efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid
[   25.887227] RIP: 0010:iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x532/0x5b0 [iwlwifi]
[   25.887287]  iwl_fwrt_dump_error_logs+0x29/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   25.887312]  iwl_mvm_nic_error+0x61/0xf0 [iwlmvm]
[   25.887339]  iwl_trans_sync_nmi_with_addr+0xa3/0x130 [iwlwifi]
[   25.887357]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0x40/0x50 [iwlwifi]
[   25.887377]  iwl_fw_dbg_error_collect+0x67/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   25.887399]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x8ed/0xbb0 [iwlmvm]
[   25.887429]  _iwl_op_mode_start+0x78/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   25.887448]  iwl_opmode_register+0x6d/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   25.887470]  iwl_mvm_init+0x3a/0x1000 [iwlmvm]
[   25.887586] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
[   25.911052] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 17.3216344376.0 3160-17.ucode
[   25.911059] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   25.911062] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   25.911064] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   25.911067] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   25.911069] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   25.911071] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   25.911073] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   25.911075] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[   25.911077] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   25.911079] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   25.911081] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   25.911083] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   25.911085] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   25.911087] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   25.911089] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   25.911091] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   25.911094] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   25.911096] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   25.911098] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[   25.911100] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   25.911102] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   25.911104] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   25.911106] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   25.911108] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   25.911110] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   25.911112] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   25.911114] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   25.911116] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   25.911118] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   25.911120] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   25.911122] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   25.911125] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   25.911127] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   25.911129] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   27.821684] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[   27.989078] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: retry init count 2
```

Booted off 16.04 USB. Twice successful in seeing wireless, once not (INIT failed again). Not sure what it means to sometimes fail, others succeed. When it succeeded `dmesg | grep iwl` gave

```
[   16.490779] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   16.810877] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.948900127.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   17.433372] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   17.454301] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: d0:7e:35:6b:fd:9b
[   17.605741] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   17.628702] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: It  does sound a bit hardware-like if it’s intermittent across more than one os. Can you try other networks (eg tethering to a mobile phone hotspot) to confirm it’s a problem with the laptop’s WiFi rather than the network itself?

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the network, it's the laptop. Ubuntu can't see the device itself which is wlp2s0 (when it did). `sudo iwlist scan` doesn't show the device only the loopback and the ethernet